# Hello World C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Every time I try and run the Simple Hello World program in C++, I build it and it says nothing to build for FirstProject. The code looks correct, I'm using MinGW as my compiler, etc. Every time I try to run the program, instead of printing the output, it just terminates. Anyone have a clue?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() { 
cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add this line of code before return statement

    system("pause");

Comment: how do you compile it?

Comment: Before return 0 add `getch()`

Comment: make: *** [src/HelloWorld.o] Error 1
src/subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'src/HelloWorld.o' failed

Is what I get then.

Comment: I tried compiling with both MinGW and Cygwin same thing for both. Builds but doesn't print the output to console

Comment: Good Grief, why would you use non-standard system-pause or getch when there's a perfectly standard getchar()?

Comment: Why use any of the above when you can find a proper command-line interface for your command-line program?

Answer (score 2):

try these commands:

```
g++ -o hello_world.exe hello_world.cpp  
./hello_world.exe
```

MinGW works same as gcc on linux so all commands which work on linux should work on MinGW

Answer (score 1):

In cygwin, the following steps should work.

1. Save the contents to file `HelloWorld.cc`.
2. Go to the directory where you saved the file.
3. Execute `make HelloWorld`
4. Execute `./HelloWorld.exe`

If that doesn't work, something is really not right.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running it from the command line or an IDE? Sometimes an IDE will open a terminal and close it too fast for you to see, or you'll just see a flash. Try running it from the command line so you'll be able to see if it printed anything before exiting the program.

Answer (score 0):

Tried and tested using MinGW in windows 10 command prompt.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello, World!"<<endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

[Image of command prompt output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLk81.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Save the contents to file `HelloWorld.cpp`
2. Go to the directory where you saved the file.
3. Execute `make HelloWorld`
4. Execute `./HelloWorld.exe`